# Display Row number of cells in a column that are not blank

Tags: excel-formula

I am using Office 365.
I have a sheet with a column of relevant values.  In a separate sheet of the same workbook, I want to display EVERY row number of cells in a column that are not blank.

The FIRST formula DID work, but it is NOT working anymore.  This is where I need help.  Is something off here?  I don't think I changed anything, but it seemed to just stop working last week, after working well for a couple months.

=IFERROR(SMALL(INDEX(('Patient Tracker'!$A$4:$A$848="")*10^10+ROW('Patient Tracker'!$A$4:$A$848),0),ROW('Patient Tracker'!A1)),"")

The "  *10^10+ROW  " is to later be able to copy down this formula and draw from this new column of indexed data by using this formula:
=IF(A2<500,INDEX('Patient Tracker'!$A$4:$D$848,A2-3,1),"")
So, if <500, it returns a blank.

THIS formula successfully returns the value of cells that are not blank from the same sheet. This is good, but I want the ROW number of the cell where this data comes from, AND I don't want the blank cells to be copied over to the new sheet, which this formula does.

=IFERROR(INDEX('Patient Tracker'!$A$4:$A$848, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK('Patient Tracker'!$A$4:$A$848), "", ROW('Patient Tracker'!$A$4:$A$848)-MIN(ROW('Patient Tracker'!$A$4:$A$848))+1), ROW(A1))),"")

Please be pateint and specific with me. I barely understand the formulas I am using.

Comment: I tested your formula and it is still working. What version of Excel are you using? If you are using Office 365 version of Excel, you may try this formula in the first cell of the column that you want to return the values: `=FILTER('Patient Tracker'!$A$4:$A$848,LEN('Patient Tracker'!$A$4:$A$848)>0)` Make sure there is no data in the column otherwise you may get a SPILL error.

Comment: It's an array function. Did you enter the formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`?

Comment: I am using Office 365.  I couldn't tell if it was an array or just a reference, so I tried with and without Ctrl-Shft-Enter. Thank you. I'll try the alternative formula tomorrow when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Wow! FILTER fxn is convenient and simple.  I could have used that many times. 
But it would appear that it will still leave me without the row number.

Comment: @TerryW , I found the problem. I had a #Ref at Row 106 in the Patient Tracker sheet.  This broke the whole array. I apologize for the waste of time.